# symfony2 behat/mink HTTP POST not using test env database

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing, behat, mink

I'm using Symfony 2.7 with Behat 3 and Behat/mink 1.5 (as is in composer.json).

```
behat.yml:

default:
suites:
    default:
        contexts:
            - FeatureContext:
                service: '@user.service'
extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url: http://api.localhost.dev
        goutte: ~
        selenium2: ~
    Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
```

I'm creating a JSON API and also created 2 databases, one for DEV and another for TEST ("my-db" & "my-db-test")

```
config_test.yml:
...
doctrine:
dbal:
    host:     127.0.0.1
    dbname:   my-db-test
    user:     root
    password: root

config_dev.yml:
...
doctrine:
dbal:
    host:     127.0.0.1
    dbname:   my-db-dev
    user:     root
    password: root
```

My problem start when trying to run a Scenario that makes a POST HTTP request (using Guzzle as client) to the server.

```
Scenario: Create a programmer
Given I have the payload:
"""
{
  "name": "John",
  "lastname" : "Doe",
  "username": "john.doe",
  "email": "john.doe@email.com",
  "password": "password",
  "birth": "10/10/1970",
  "type": "normal"
}
"""
When I request "POST" "/users"
Then the response status code should be "201"
And the "Location" header should be "http://api.localhost.dev/users/john.doe"
```

In the FeatureContext.php file I have a @Before scenario

```
/**
 * @BeforeScenario
 */
public function clearData()
{
   $this->_service->deleteUsers();
}
```

That correctly deletes the TEST DDBB as expected.
The problem is that the HTTP POST request goes through the Controller (obviously) and then hit the service to create a user in the DEV database (instead of using the recently cleaned TEST DDBB)

When I run a GET Scenario using a TableNode data:

```
 | name | lastname| username | email             |  password  |birth       | type|
 | John | Doe     | john.doe |john.doe@email.com |  password  | 10/10/1970 | normal |
```

The test actually hits the TEST env (Because I insert the user directly using the service, WITHOUT going through the Controller action "postUserAction") so everything goes well.

Does anyone know how to use the TEST database always and not only when using the service? All the POST request fails after the first (as a UNIQUE constraint prevents the user being inserted) so the tests fails.

Thanks to all and let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Why don't you use: http://api.localhost.dev/app_test.php ?

Comment: Try what @COil says. That is how you should do it. A bit of [examples](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/behat) for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. Actually, if I use "app_test.php" in REST Chrome client, the request goes correctly to the Test DB. But if I enter the 'base_uri' => 'http://api.localhost.dev/app_test.php' into Guzzle, the request still goes through dev env (as the dev.log) file logs the Exception of a Doctrine unique constraint being raised. Weird